# GWT Designer - no editor is opening up, no compile button is displayed

Tags: gwt

I have the following installed

> GWT
>   Designer  2.5.0.r37x201202061331  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.feature.feature.group   Google,
>   Inc.
>
> GWT Designer
>   Core  2.5.0.r37x201202052353  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.feature.feature.group    Google,
>   Inc.
>
> GWT Designer
>   Editor    2.5.0.r37x201202061313  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group    Google,
>   Inc.
>
> GWT Designer
>   GPE   2.5.0.r37x201201030222  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gpe.feature.feature.group   Google,
>   Inc.

I am able to use GWT Wizards to setup GWT projects, however, when I open a ui.xml file, I only get an XML editor (no designer).  Also there is no GWT compile button anywhere.  I have tried right clicking on the project but there is no Google menu there or any button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

first of all do you have designer plugin if not add it.
if u have the plugin then close the first tag of your web  xml file. it will open up designer. For compilation write clickon project go to google option and then to gwt compile option to compile your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly installed the GPE Plugins.

- Right click the ui file
- Open with
- WindowBuilder Editor

Two tabs are located in the left-button corner. click Design.